# ORM Architecture: One or Multiple Models (Entity Framework)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm

**Scenario:**

I'm working on a solution that has many assemblies.  The main assembly references a DAL assembly with a large EF model.  I am working on a DLL that contains its own smaller EF model.  Both models will connect to the same database.  The DLL that I am working on will return data to the main assembly, but it doesn't necessarily have to return entities from its model.

**Question:**

Is it better for each sub-assembly to contain its own small model or should they all share the same large model?

**Discussion:**

- On one hand, if I shared the main assembly's model, the sub-assembly could return entities to the main assembly.
- On the other hand, sharing one large model couples each assembly to that model.  It seems like this would increase the chance that a change to that model could break a sub-assembly.  I may not be able to safely make useful changes to the main model in fear of breaking one of the sub-assemblies.

**Edit:**

1. Ray Vernagus had some good points (I think) about setting clearly defined boundries around your models.  I *really* like this idea.  I am kind of doing this already by having a separate model in my subassembly, since my subassembly has a clearly defined scope.  Is this enough?
2. Consider the situation where all of the domain models were in the same DAL assembly and many of the entities were based on the same tables and had the same names.  Besides needing to be in saparate namespaces, would this be a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric Evans describes this situation aptly in his book, [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215). His recommendation is to set boundaries around your models and to explicitly define the scope within which they apply. This is known as [Bounded Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Bounded_context) and [Context Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Context_map).

It sounds like you need to be explicit about whether or not you want to have one common Domain Model or whether each DAL assembly should be bounded to its own Model. If you want one central Domain Model, you may want to consider defining such in your main assembly and then have your DAL assemblies communicate with it through that model. Otherwise, you can keep to the separate models per DAL assembly but define explicit Bounded Contexts.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph.  I had to read the second paragraph several times before I understood what you were saying.  ;-p

Comment: Read the book! I certainly can't do it justice. =)

Comment: Part of the problem is that I don't know what I want (hence the question). My boss wants one giant model in a single DAL assembly that everyone uses. I tend to favor breaking the model in to smaller sub-models, whether or not they are in separate assemblies. In this particular case, the sub-model is NOT in a DAL assembly, but instead embedded in to the business sub-assembly.

Comment: Well, unfortunately the sprint that I'm on ends in less than a week, and I need to make a decision well before I'd even receive the book if I bought it.

Comment: If you have 15 minutes you can watch this interview with Eric Evans where he talks more about Bounded Context: http://www.infoq.com/interviews/domain-driven-design-eric-evans

Answer (score 2):

I have used both types, and I believe that the sub model is far better. Especially of the complete model would be large and the different subsets relatively independent. Or used locally in conceptually different part of the solutions. You get a collection of cleaner solutions (scales better complexity-wise) and you seldom have changes that effect several conceptually different system areas.

The biggest issue is if you have several parts of the system stretching over several conceptual areas, since it is not trivial (but bridgeable) to jump between models...

BR

Daniel

Comment: I am leaning this way for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use one large model for maintainability reasons. In any case, when your model changes because of database changes in the schema, you have to propagate those changes so if you have more than one model ...

Comment: I'm not too concerned about changes to the store model.  The type of changes that I'm referring to are changes to the 'conceptual' model.