# Entity Framework Plugin Architecture Recommendation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, plugins, mef, repository-pattern

I am trying to build a modularized ASP.NET MVC application using Areas and Dependency Injection. The application currently consists of the following projects:

- **Framework.Contracts** (Interfaces for Authentication Service, Authorization, Logging)
- **Framework** (Implementation of Authentication Service, Authorization, ...)
- **Framework.Web** (MVC Web Application)

Each plugin consists of an MVC Area project, contracts and service implementation:

- **EmployeesPlugin.Contracts** (Interfaces for IEmployeesService)
- **EmployeesPlugin** (Implentation for IEmployeesService)
- **EmployeesPlugin.MVC**

I want to use Entity Framework Database First or Model First (since I have to connect an existing database). My problem is that I do not know how to loosly couple my entities. I do not want to put them into a single shared DatabaseLayer project. Rather I would like to define central entities (User, Settings, LogEntries, ...) for the Framework project and additional entities (like Employee, Company) for each plugin.

After reading [ORM Architecture: One or Multiple Models (Entity Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260200/orm-architecture-one-or-multiple-models-entity-framework) I thought about creating multiple Models (i.e. Multiple Data Contexts). Actually I do not like the idea of having redundant code.

I thought about creating interfaces that expose the properties of each entity. These interfaces will be put in a project per Plugin. Like `IEmployee` exposing `FirstName` and `LastName`. Then I started to create an `IEmployeeRepository` to return and create, edit and delete Employees. However creating employees does not work when only exposing `IEmployee` and no concrete class.

Another problem is that the entity `Employee` contains references to entities in other projects/plugins. Lets say a employee hosts a number of projects. Thus I thought to create a generic `IEmployee` interface without the reference to the project and an `IEmployeeProjects` interface containing the reference to the projects. That way I could create a class `Employee` in a central database layer project that implement both `IEmployee` add `IEmployeeProjects:

```
public class Employee : IEmployee, IEmployeeProjects
{   
    // From IEmployee interface
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // From IEmployeeProject interface
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to plump things together using the Entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

You create loose couply by removing any hard relationships between them. Instead just use Ids to refer to other entities. This also means that each plugin uses it's own DbContext.

Then use repositories in each plugin to load the referenced entities. That also means that each plugin have to define their repository interfaces in a seperate assembly which can be used by other plugins.

I also typically create a core object where I define all entites, services and repositories that the core exposes.